# Using rspec with a local gem

Tags: ruby, rspec, rubygems, bundler

I am using a local gem (on my machine) with another application that is a command line app.

I have something like this in the gemfile to refer to the local gem:

```
gem 'mygem', :path => '/Users/devmachine/Projects/mygem'
```

When I run bundle console I am able to use the gem and all is well. However, whenever I run my test suite (rspec) I get the following message:

```
ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mygem (LoadError)
```

I'm confused. Any ideas?

Comment: did you try `bundle exec rspec` ? if you are not using the bundle environment somehow rspec won't know what you put in your Gemfile but just use the gems it finds installed

Comment: @ascar how about putting that into an answer so future readers can easily find the solution and you receive the points ?

Comment: @rockskull i did post it as a answer, was going to anyway but just wanted to be sure he didn't try it already before posting an unnecessary answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to run:

`bundle exec rspec`

If you are not using the bundle evironment rspec won't know what you put in your Gemfile and just use the Gems it finds installed.